# What to import to use Facebook Graph API in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I need user friends list. I understood how to login to FB from app with button. But now I can not come across on this line:

Which header file should I import to use Graph API?

```
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{friendlist-id}"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
```

I installed frameworks see below, and included some header. But can not see any graph stuff.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

[image]

Comment: which sdk are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using in this way as it is updated in SDK 4.0

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:nil]
    startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
         NSLog(@”fetched user:%@”, result);
      }
  }];
```

Refer to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#fetching

Comment: did u get ur friendslist ?

Comment: When I declare FBSDKGraphRequest *request, it says 'Use of unidentified identifier FBSDKGraphRequest'. Though I have imported <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> too, what may be the problem?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj try using #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h> as it is changed in updated version